# How to position element of different size inside the grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to using grid cell positioning with rows and columns. I understand that this will place the button in only one cell:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Hello" />
```

What if I wanted the button to be placed over four adjacent cells? Is it possible to do? I understand that I can change the height width of column and row respectively, but I have many elements on the screen which are of different size, and for example, I have the situation where the button of one specific width is placed below the button which is twice wide.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with

```
Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
```

So your code would look like this :

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="Hello" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Grid.ColumnSpan` and/or the `Grid.RowSpan` properties:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="Hello" />
```